# Store array in C permanantly

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I write a program in C/C++ and create an array of certain size. I want to keep that permanently even if I switch off the computer and later access it. Is there a way to do that? If so do let me know and also after saving it, how to access it.

Comment: use [Files](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm)

Comment: Save it in a file. Load it when your program starts.

Comment: You mean, how can you read and write files? Pick a language, and use the standard library, [`<stdio.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c) in C or [`<iostreams>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) in C++.

Comment: No No, if I use file how would that help me out? It will just store the data not the file structure right? suppose I have a linked list, I want it to be present always. If i save in the file then again I have to create alinked list to store the data after reading from file. I do not want to create the structure again, how would I do that?

Comment: Why do you asking about _array_ in question and saying _linked list_ in comment?  There are tons of options how to __serialize__ objects in C, spend a day reading Internet about them than clarify your question.

Comment: I gave it as an example, any structure, like B tree b+ tree linear linked lists,arrays, hash tables.. Need to store these permanently

Comment: You need [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: Most computers don't have persistent memory (at least, not for use by user programs), and there's no standard way to use it even if you do have some available. You're going to have to read and write files if you want to store data permanently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the data to a file and load it on programm start.

Comment: Ordinarily this would be a bad answer, but considering the question it seems pretty good.

Comment: No No, if I use file how would that help me out? It will just strore the data not the file structure right?

Comment: @JonathanPotter My answers are generally a bit more detailed. But in this case the short answer seems more straight forward.

Comment: @user3237995 what is "the file structure"? Files store whatever you store in them. A file is just a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Say you create a vector of MAX size for a string:

```
char * str = (char *) malloc( MAX );
```

At some point, you fill it with some data:

```
strcpy( str, "Useful data in the form of a string" );
```

Finally, at the program's end, you save it to a file:

```
FILE * f = fopen( "data.bin", "wb" );
fwrite( str, 1, MAX, f );
fclose( f );
```

At the beginning of the next execution, you'd like to load it:

```
char * str = (char *) malloc( MAX );
FILE * f = fopen( "data.bin", "rb" );
fread( str, 1, MAX, f );
fclose( f );
```

This solution has a few shortcomings: for example your data will be only useful for the computer in which you saved it. If you want portability, then you should use text and XML: http://www.jclark.com/xml/expat.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a memory mapped file and use offsets in the memory mapped file in place of pointers. You would have to implement your own dynamic block allocation management in the memory mapped file.

Using offsets would be less efficient than pointers. But you would load and save the data structure in a snap.

It is possible to avoid the use of offset and use real pointers instead. To do this, you save the pointer value to the memory mapped file when you close the memory mapped file. When you load the memory mapped file, you would then have to adjust all pointers in the data structure by adding the offset of the pointer to the memory mapped file.

If the data structure is small, you could do it in one pass when the file is mapped into memory. If the data structure is big, you could do it in a lazy way and only fix pointers of struct when you access them for the first time.